# Is there a way to make screen reader read new content (or content that appear) on the document? role alert works only with few tags

Tags: firefox, accessibility, alert, screen-readers, role

I'm trying to make screen reader read some content that switch from `display:none` to `display:block`. I think using `role="alert"` is a good way but it works only if content is in a `div`, `p` or `span`.

But my content is a mix of `div`, `span`, `p` and other tags that screen reader doesn't read (like `h1`, `ul`, `li`, and others).

How can I make screen reader read all the content?

There's an example:

```
<button onclick="show()">
  Show
</button>

<div id="button" style="display:none" role="alert">
  Lettera A
  <div>
    Lettera B
    <h1>
    Lettera E
    </h1>
    <div>
      Lettera C
      <ul>
        <li>Lettera D</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function show() {
  $('#button').show();
}
```

In this example, screen reader (i use NVDA on Firefox on Windows) read only:

Lettera A

Lettera B

Lettera C

Answer (score 0):

The [aria-live property](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-live) is just what you are looking for. It is used to indicate that an element will be updated, and describes the types of updates the user agents, assistive technologies, and user can expect from the live region.

> When regions are specified as polite, assistive technologies will notify users of updates but generally do not interrupt the current task, and updates take low priority. When regions are specified as assertive, assistive technologies will immediately notify the user, and could potentially clear the speech queue of previous updates

Comment: I tried to implement aria-live property before asking, but i think i made some mistakes. Can you implement it for me in a fiddle, using the example above (the code in my question)?

Comment: with this solution, screen reader (NVDA on Firefox on windows in my case) say only "frame show button"

Comment: This should probably work better. It seems that aria-live doesn't work well with hidden content. It only really works when there are changes to the DOM. https://jsfiddle.net/ffuckkpj/3/